# what is the point for ExpressionTree's node such as BinaryExpression to receive MethodInfo argument?

Tags: c#

```
public abstract class Expression
{
   public static BinaryExpression Add(Expression left, Expression right);
   public static BinaryExpression Add(Expression left, Expression right, MethodInfo method);
   // ...
}
```

I don't understand what's the point to have a parameter for the last parameter, `MethodInfo method`, isn't that we already use `Add`, which means "+", just like:

```
Expression sumExpr = Expression.Add(
    Expression.Constant(1),
    Expression.Constant(2)
);
```

so under what circumstances we need to use the last parameters `MethodInfo method`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Method` member of `BinaryExpression` is used when the operator is not one of the built-in operators between numeric types. This happens e.g. when the type has defined its own operator (e.g. with `public static T operator +(T x, T y)`), or when you're doing string concatenation (which the compiler lowers down to a call to `string.Concat`).

For example, if you write:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static Foo operator +(Foo x, Foo y) => new Foo();
}

Expression<Func<Foo, Foo>> e = x => x + x;
```

You'll see that the `BinaryExpression.Method` property is set to Foo's `op_Addition` operator.

Likewise, if you use string concatenation:

```
Expression<Func<string, string>> e = name => "Hello, " + name;
```

You'll see that the `Method` property of the `BinaryExpression` is set to the `MethodInfo` of the `string.Concat` method.

[See on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxAJwK4wD4AEBMBGAWACgsAGAAizwDoAZWAR2oFEAPAB2QFMBnHqAPYweAbmLE2nXvyEAeLAFZ5eUnEoqAfBvJc85ALzkYEMFwPaARAAkuAG1sC1F8gGojJrmJJ4AnAAoAgCFYCGQAT0luPkEYAEpdakCBABMw2OoAWS4EAAsU6gA5D1ivCQ4omRh5JQAxAUdyOoEtHRwDclZzDtcOryp/IJDwyOkY+JxElLTM7LzkwuLSkgBmSjam4gBvYnJdylWqADZG+vIBdi5kCAQBZFc/Jo61R7SumC4AdxOBPxLiAF8gA===).

Comment: thanks for your answer, so is `op_Addition` the same as + operator overload ?

Comment: @sydevloper yes, It is a special name generated by compiler for this operator overload.

Comment: Yep, the `+` operator gets compiled into a static method called `op_Addition`

Comment: @canton7 Hi mate, could you have a  look at this expression tree question please? thank you in advance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72588731/why-invocationexpression-throws-an-unreachable-exception-by-default-in-expressio

Answer (score 1):

Because you can overload operators in C#. If your expression uses an overloaded operator, that operator will be the method info. It represents the "implementing method" of the operation, as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.add?view=net-6.0#system-linq-expressions-expression-add(system-linq-expressions-expression-system-linq-expressions-expression-system-reflection-methodinfo)) says. Example:

```
public class Foo {
    public void M() {
        Expression<Func<Foo, Foo, Foo>> e = (x, y) => x + y;
    }
    
    public static Foo operator +(Foo a, Foo b)
        => new Foo();
}
```

Using [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLRIMYHsEBNXIwJwYzIA0uIA1AD4ACATAIwCwAUPQAwAE9zAOgAyASwB2ARwEBRAB4AHJMmQisY5AG4O9AMx9GPAGJYsPAN4ceVvnvoAWHgFkAFAEpzl617mKUKtQA89ACsAcZY5EYmkeEAfLE8EDwAvDzOspEAnu7JCbI81DyZWuxeAL6eVpU2fMwAbFGmWPIQCLA4Bc7hPFAxJjzArtVeuTxiEADujW4lZUA), we can see that this lowers to:

```
ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo), "x");
ParameterExpression parameterExpression2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo), "y");
BinaryExpression body = Expression.Add(parameterExpression, parameterExpression2, (MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle((RuntimeMethodHandle)/*OpCode not supported: LdMemberToken*/));
ParameterExpression[] array = new ParameterExpression[2];
array[0] = parameterExpression;
array[1] = parameterExpression2;
Expression<Func<Foo, Foo, Foo>> expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, Foo, Foo>>(body, array);
```

Notice that it uses the overload of `Expression.Add` with the method info parameter.

Comment: Hi mate, can you have a look at this expression tree question please, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72588731/why-invocationexpression-throws-an-unreachable-exception-by-default-in-expressio